# Tomcat creates 0 byte files

Tags: java, selenium, tomcat5.5

I have a very simple file upload mechanism in java. I just take the file and save it on the server. I'm testing this simple code with selenium and when a timeout occurs in the selenium test tomcat creates 0 byte files under tomcat_home/work/Catalina/localhost/uploadServlet/ directory as MultiPart* files. It creates thousands of files, until there is no disk space left on device. What may cause this problem? How can I solve this? Is there anyone has an idea about this?

My environment is: Ubuntu - 8.04 server, apache tomcat - 5.5.29, sun java 1.6

Thanks,

Here is the code snippet that i use

```
    String strFileName = request.getParameter("FileName");
    String strPath = request.getParameter("Path");
    File fFile = (File) request.getAttribute("Content");

    int index = strPath.length() - 1; 
    if (strPath.charAt(index) != '/') {
        strPath += "/";
    }
    if (! new File(strPath).exists()) {
        new File(strPath).mkdirs();
    }
    File file = new File(strPath + strFileName);
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fFile);

    byte[] bBuf = new byte[1024];

    int iBufLen = 0;
    int iReadLen = 1024;
    int iTotelLen = 0;
    /*read 1024 bytes at a time*/
    while ((iBufLen = fileInputStream.read(bBuf)) != -1) {
        fileOutputStream.write(bBuf);
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        iTotelLen += iBufLen;
        if (fileInputStream.available() < iReadLen) {
            iReadLen = fileInputStream.available();
            break;
        }
    }

    byte[] tempbBuf = new byte[iReadLen];
    fileInputStream.read(tempbBuf, 0, iReadLen);

    fileOutputStream.write(tempbBuf);

    fileOutputStream.close();
    fileInputStream.close();

    if (fFile.exists()) {
        fFile.delete();
    }
```

Comment: Please help us help you by posting your actual code :-)

Comment: Are you calling `flush()` and or `close()` on the `OutputStream` or `Writer` after you're done writing the file?

Comment: i've edited the post and inserted the simple code

Comment: Using available() is not correct for stream pumping!  You must only rely on the return from the read().  available() is only an "instantaneous" check; some bytes may be available "soon" after that call, e.g. after lower-level flow control resumes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [apache commons file upload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) class and i've deleted the temporary files in the finally section. The problem is solved with this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that some sort of exception is occuring in the middle of this code? Best to close the streams in a `finally` block.

Comment: I've tried this one but the result doesn't change numerous 0 bytes.

Comment: do you know for sure that request.getAttribute("Content") contains anything with content? this part of the code is left out