# How to delete many 0 byte files in linux?

Tags: linux, file, find, xargs, delete-file

I've a directory with many number of 0 byte files in it. I can't even see the files when I use the ls command. I'm using a small script to delete these files but sometimes that does not even delete these files. Here is the script:

```
i=100
while [ $i -le 999 ];do
    rm -f file${i}*;
    let i++;
done
```

Is there any other way to do this more quickly?

Comment: If the files are 0 bytes and 'ls' does not show them, how do you know they are there?

Comment: I know because I was able to see them a few times, this 0 byte files occured several times and i don't know when and how but sometimes i could see them sometimes as now i could not see them. However i know the reason of the problem and it occured again, therefore i know they are in that directory

Comment: other than `while [ $i -le 999]` and `let i++`, you can also use `seq` with `for i in $(seq ...)`

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Use `find` combined with `xargs`.

```
find . -name 'file*' -size 0 -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

You avoid to start `rm` for every file.

Comment: +1 for `xargs`. Much better than `-exec`. Consider use `-print0` and `-0` for safety.

Comment: Thanks, i'm giving a shot for this one. I'll be posting the result.

Comment: `-exec` will start a new process with each argument. `xargs` won't. This is a great improvement in the number of process to start, and a great improvement in execution time. See `man xargs` for more info.

Comment: edit: Yes, it worked!...(my mistake) Great thanks, it is not that fast but it is handy

Comment: You want to use -size 0c. -size 0 will include files less than 512bytes.

Comment: @tumtumtum It is true that `-size 0c` would be more correct (no unit specified default to number of blocks), but you're wrong in stating that `-size 0` will include files less than 512 bytes. Indeed, as soon as a file is 1 byte in size, it occupies 1 block.

Comment: This works for Ubuntu:  `find . -type f -name '*' -size 0 -print0 | xargs -r0 rm`

Comment: Warning: If you are new to `POSIX` based system, you should know device files in `POSIX` systems are 0 bytes in length. i.e. your keyboard is a device.

Comment: Should include `-type f` as seanbreeden suggests.  otherwise can folders will be included  and will abort the rm call prematurely

Answer (score 96):

With GNU's `find` (see comments), there is no need to use xargs :

```
find -name 'file*' -size 0 -delete
```

Comment: Nice - I didn't realize find had a delete action.

Comment: Only in GNU find.  POSIX does not specify actions like -delete and -ls

Comment: Note that obviously you don't need the `-name 'file*'` part if you don't filter by name.

Comment: To just make the copy-and-pasteable solution of Skippys comment, just use `find . -size 0 -delete`

Comment: How could I use is on a specific folder path, something like: `/home/user/file*` @coredump

Comment: @alper `find` accepts a directory as its first argument, i.e. `find /home/user/ -name "file* ..."`. **Highly recommended: first use with `-print` instead of `-delete`, and then only when the result is satisfying, delete files**.

Comment: Why should I use `-print` before `-delete`?  As I understand correctly, if `find ./ -type f -size 0 -print` returns valid output then I can do: `find ./ -type f -size 0 -delete` @coredump

Comment: @alper Yes, first try with print (instead of delete), and if that works, you can delete safely (two separate commands)

Answer (score 13):

If you want to find and remove all 0-byte files in a folder:

```
find /path/to/folder -size 0 -delete
```

Answer (score 7):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size 0 -delete
```

This finds the files with size 0  in the current directory, without going into sub-directories, and deletes them.

To list the files without removing them:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size 0
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following command:

> find . -maxdepth 1 -size 0c -exec rm {} \;

And if are looking to delete the 0 byte files in subdirectories as well, omit `-maxdepth 1` in previous command and execute.

Answer (score 4):

Delete all files named file... in the current directory:

```
find . -name file* -maxdepth 1 -exec rm {} \;
```

This will still take a long time, as it starts `rm` for every file.

Comment: I guess you should use double quotes: -name "file*"  
  
Otherwise the pattern will be expanded by the shell.

Comment: This doesn't limit the `rm` to files with 0 bytes. To be fair, though, neither does the code the OP posted.

Comment: You can use `+` instead of `;` to have `find` call `rm` with multiple arguments instead of invoking a process for each file.

Answer (score 2):

you can even use the option -delete which will delete the file.

from man find,
 -delete
              Delete  files;  true  if removal succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, trying it yourself will help this to make sense:

```
bash-2.05b$ touch empty1 empty2 empty3
bash-2.05b$ cat > fileWithData1
Data Here
bash-2.05b$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r--    1 user group           0 Jul  1 12:51 empty1
-rw-rw-r--    1 user group           0 Jul  1 12:51 empty2
-rw-rw-r--    1 user group           0 Jul  1 12:51 empty3
-rw-rw-r--    1 user group          10 Jul  1 12:51 fileWithData1
bash-2.05b$ find . -size 0 -exec rm {} \;
bash-2.05b$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r--    1 user group          10 Jul  1 12:51 fileWithData1
```

If you have a look at the man page for find (type `man find`), you will see an array of powerful options for this command.

Answer (score 1):

*"...sometimes that does not even delete these files"* makes me think this might be something you do regularly. If so, this Perl script will remove any zero-byte regular files in your current directory. It avoids rm altogether by using a system call (unlink), and is quite fast.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @files = glob "* .*";
for (@files) {
    next unless -e and -f;
    unlink if -z;
}
```

Comment: Hm, it works for me. It must have something to do with your other (Java/Selenium-related) problem. Either that, or the files you're trying to remove aren't regular files. I don't think the code is faulty.

Answer (score 0):

Going up a level it's worth while to figure out why the files are there. You're just treating a symptom by deleting them. What if some program is using them to lock resources? If so your deleting them could be leading to corruption.

lsof is one way you might figure out which processes have a handle on the empty files.

Comment: The reason is why they are there is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157144/tomcat-creates-0-byte-files
I'm also trying to solve that problem